# Running Romex Along Shed Ceiling

Tags: electrical, wiring, cables, cable-management

We have been working on running electric to our outdoor shed recently, and are wondering what is the preferred way of attaching the romex along the vaulted/pitched ceiling for the lights.

The light boxes are about 5 feet apart from one another, and have 2 or so joists running in between them.  From what I've read, we shouldn't drill holes, so would you just staple the romex to the underside of the joists? Or possibly run conduit between them and attach the conduit to the underside of the joists?

[image: Ceiling]

Comment: Conduit would be awesome, but don't run Romex through it.  For one thing it must be very large if you do.  Run THHN individual wires.

Comment: You could staple the Romex to the joists terminate in a box then wire the lights or install receptacles (receptacles need to be GFCI protected).  I would want a few more joists, creating ties, if you get any snow load at all that OSB may not hold up.